# dll for machine on 64 and IIS runs as 32 bit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have an web project which is target for framework 3.5, but the web server is 64 bit and its IIS runs on 32 bits. I need to import the dll but there are various and I don't know which one is fit for my project. There are net2.0 and net3.5. Do I use the dll for net3.5? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS, under sites, there is an application pool specified for each site. You can specify there whether the application runs on 2.0 or 3.5. IIS probably already has the DLLs.